# Seaborn FacetGrid 'hue' changed number of bars

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I want to plot facetgrid with seaborn and use 'hue' to identify the number is large or small. However, when I includes 'hue', the number of bars changed.

Generating data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(0)

groups = ('Group 1', 'Group 2')
means = ('Low', 'High', 'Mid')
index =  pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [groups, means], 
   names=['Group', 'Mean']
)
values = np.random.randint(low=20, high=100, size=len(index))
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'val': values}, index=index).reset_index()
data['is_positive'] = data['val'] > 75
```

```
    Group   Mean    val is_positive
0   Group 1 Low     64  False
1   Group 1 High    67  False
2   Group 1 Mid     84  True
3   Group 2 Low     87  True
4   Group 2 High    87  True
5   Group 2 Mid     29  False
```

If I don't use 'hue', it shows all bars. However, the `color_palette` is not applied.

```
colors = ["red", "green"]
customPalette = sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="Group", hue='is_positive', height=3, col_wrap=6, palette=customPalette)
g.map(sns.barplot, 'val', 'Mean')
```

[image]

If I use 'hue', the color is correct but it only shows two bars.

[image]

Ideal chart will show all bars and apply the color_palette. Please help and explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass `order` option to `barplot`:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Group", height=3, hue='is_positive', 
                  col_wrap=6, palette=customPalette)
g.map(sns.barplot, 'val', 'Mean', order=['Low','Mid','High'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why, but from the warning that seaborn pumps out when `order` is removed, my guess is that `seaborn` doesn't align the order of `hue` automatically, leading to misalignment across the axes.

Comment: You'll want to heed the advice in the second paragraph [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), along with the warning in the big orange box.

Answer (score 0):

The [seaborn.FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) Warning suggests using relplot() or catplot()

> Warning
>
> When using seaborn functions that infer semantic mappings from a
> dataset, care must be taken to synchronize those mappings across
> facets (e.g., by defing the hue mapping with a palette dict or setting
> the data type of the variables to category). In most cases, it will be
> better to use a figure-level function (e.g. relplot() or catplot())
> than to use FacetGrid directly.